# Counting files in directory with a specific string stored in a variable using batch script and writing the count in a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to count all the files that have Yesterday's date in their filename and then write that count in a text file. I have stored the value of yesterday's date in a variable %YesterdayDate% however this line
for %F in (%YesterdayDate%*) do (set /a counter+=1)
doesn't seem to be picking the files with yesterday's date in their name. Below is the code

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A "YYYY=%DATE:~10,4%, MM=1%DATE:~4,2%-100, DD=1%DATE:~7,2%-101, Feb=28+^!(YYYY%%4)"
set "DPM= 31 31 %Feb% 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30"
if %DD% equ 0 set /A "MM+=M=-1,DD=0%DPM: =+^!(MM-(M+=1))*%,YYYY-=^!MM,MM+=12*^!MM"
set /A "MM+=100,DD+=100"
set "YesterdayDate=%YYYY%%MM:~1%%DD:~1%"
echo %YesterdayDate%


Rem get today's date
set m=%date:~-7,2%
set /A m -= 1
set DATE_DIR=%date:~-10,2%-%m%-%date:~-4,4%
echo %DATE_DIR%

Rem Loop through and count backup
set counter=0
for %F in (%YesterdayDate%*) do (set /a counter+=1)
>>test1.txt echo logfile  for %DATE_DIR%
>>test1.txt echo Number of backups :%counter%
```

Comment: In a batch-file, use `%%F` instead of `%F`, which is command-line syntax.

Comment: Hie @Stephan thank you very much for the contribution. 
when I use %%F this is what I get  and it still doesn't count the number of files i desire.

`C:\Users\david>for %%F in (*%YesterdayDate%) do (set /a counter+=1)
%%F was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: it's a single `%` directly on the command line, but two `%%` in batch files.

Comment: Once the `%(%)F` problem is sorted, you're going to have problems with your date calculations. `set m=%date:~-7,2% / set /A m -= 1` will set `m` to a 2-digit number, then subtract 1 yielding a 1-digit number if `m` is 01..07, `-1` if `m` is 08 or 09 and will be correct 2-digit if `m` is 10 or greater.